# Union and Intersection of Recursively Enumerable sets

Tags: java, recursion, enumeration, computation-theory

I am having a hard time writing a code for this theorem:
If A and B are recursively enumerable sets, then so are A union B and A intersection B. I know RE sets are sets that contain output of recursive functions and can be enumerated such that the set is a subset of natural numbers.

For A union B:

```
public static Function<Integer, Integer> union(Function<Integer, Integer> enumA, Function<Integer, Integer> enumB){
...
}
```

Could someone give me some tips on how to go about implementing this.

Comment: I am unclear about the Function<Integer,Integer> interface you seem to be using to describe the enumerable sets themselves. Can you expand your question a bit?

Comment: I am guessing those function parameters create an enumerable set, Then we go through the set and see if any elements of set A are in set B, then we return a function where f(i) == A(i) and B(i) and then we return that function. I believe thats how the intersection would be solved.

Comment: You are guessing? To rephrase my question, what are the parameters to these functions, what are the returns? This is a mathematical question around computation theory, so the interpretation matters.

Comment: That is the same question that I have as well. The professor didn't give us a tester, as we have to write our own. All he gave us was the method declaration.

Comment: I am afraid that I won't be of much help in that case, since my university math is rusty. You will have to wait for a more knowledgeable user to assist in the answer.

Comment: So apparently we can return any output which signifies that it is recursive. If it doesn't produce any output, then it is not recursive.